# Is there an newer version or alternative for data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

When I tried to use data.table in my R project a warning saying "data.table 1.12.8 using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com" appears in the console.

I had tried to update the data.table but it was up to date.

```
library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
```

Is there any better way to load data than data.table? Does data.table slows my R project? if yes what are the memory-efficient alternatives available?

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to load data into R: the most appropriate will depend on the nature of the data.  Could you edit your post to summarise the format of the data that you are attempting to load into R?  It looks to me like the message you are receiving is a message, rather than a warning. What makes you think that there's a problem?  Try `suppressMessages(library('data.table'))` if you want to hide the message on loading the package.

Comment: This isn't really a warning. It just says you're using `data.table 1.12.8` with 4 processing threads. Can you please show us your code where you're experiencing problems *with* `data.table`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too long for comment so posting as an answer.

It is not slowing down but it is speeding up. Most of R packages will use single core, data.table on your machine will use 4 by default. This message is not a warning but a package startup message.

And addressing your questions precisely...
- there is no better way to load data than data.table ;)
- data.table does **not** slow down your project
- alternatives are coding C or C++ and using that in R

Comment: Thank you very much.